# Wordpress as Remote Posting Mechanism

Tags: wordpress

I hate Wordpress for numerous reasons, but clients love it because it gives them so many beautiful features for their blog posts.  I'm looking to see if I could use Wordpress as a means for clients to input their posts without having to actually use it as the platform for their website.

Is it doable (and is it wise?) to setup a free Wordpress account on Wordpress.com and use the generated RSS feed as a means of importing posts into their website?  Is there a different means to do this perhaps by using a Wordpress API I don't know about?  Such a setup would require a separate solution for comments, like IntenseDebate.

Curious as to what others think of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has an [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) interface, so you could write some middleware to feed your blog with an RSS feed, or simply submit content via the [XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) itself.

I'm sure there are probably some plugins (there are many to choose from) to read RSS feeds for WordPress too, but you'll have to scowl the WordPress site for the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self hosted WordPress version as your backend (and also for your client) but don't use its frontend. Instead you can use the WP REST API and build your client's site using the tecnology you like the most. There are some examples of sites built with React.js or AngularJS using the WP REST API.

Even you can configure your WP as multisite and use as a backend for many users. One installation for rule them all :P

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.labnol.org/software/download/best-desktop-blogging-clients-linux/3491/) if that's what you are looking for? I came across this in a Linux Format magazine that covered a desktop client that interacts with well known blogging API's such as wordpress such that you can blog off-line, and next time you connect, it will synchronise with the blogger....

Answer (score 0):

What about post by email? [WordPress › Postie « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/) has more features than the WP's built-in post by email function, and there are hacks described in Postie's forums about supporting multiple emails and catergories.